# Passing output with HTML tags from AngularJs to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a script that gets data from an API call that contains some HTML to properly display the data on HTML. I am getting that data from python and using flask http post to save it into a variable in AngularJs.

Please see this jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/2mydubL8/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="htmController">
  <input type="submit" ng-click="submit()" value="Submit"></input>
  <pre>{{output}}</pre> </div>
```

JS:

```
function htmController($scope) {
  //Result data comes from an API call and looks something like below
  $scope.result = '\r\n<b><mark>Hostname: switch_01:</mark></b>\r\n\r\n\r\nservice password-encryption\r\nservice compress-config\r\n!\r\nhostname switch_01\r\n!\r\nlogging buffered informational\r\nno logging console\r\naaa new-model\r\naaa authentication login default group tacacs+ line\r\n\r\n<b><mark>Hostname: switch_02:</mark></b>\r\n\r\n\r\nservice password-encryption\r\nservice compress-config\r\n!\r\nhostname switch_02\r\n!\r\nlogging buffered informational\r\nno logging console\r\naaa new-model\r\naaa authentication login default group tacacs+ line\r\n';  
  $scope.submit = function () {
     $scope.output = $scope.result;
    }
};
```

I would like the HTML page to apply the  and  tags instead of showing the tags as an output like in jsfiddle.

I am hoping the output on HTML will show "Hostname: " line with bold () and 
highlighted (). Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: try [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml).

Answer (score 0):

#### you can use `ngSanitize` to render html

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller("htmController", htmController);

function htmController($scope) {
  //Result data comes from an API call and looks something like below
  $scope.result = '\r\n<b><mark>Hostname: switch_01:</mark></b>\r\n\r\n\r\nservice password-encryption\r\nservice compress-config\r\n!\r\nhostname switch_01\r\n!\r\nlogging buffered informational\r\nno logging console\r\naaa new-model\r\naaa authentication login default group tacacs+ line\r\n\r\n<b><mark>Hostname: switch_02:</mark></b>\r\n\r\n\r\nservice password-encryption\r\nservice compress-config\r\n!\r\nhostname switch_02\r\n!\r\nlogging buffered informational\r\nno logging console\r\naaa new-model\r\naaa authentication login default group tacacs+ line\r\n';  
  $scope.submit = function () {
     $scope.output = $scope.result;
    }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="htmController">
  <input type="submit" ng-click="submit()" value="Submit">
    <p ng-bind-html="output"></p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I am running 'angular.js@1.3.0-beta.5' and unfortunately updating is not an option as it is a legacy app. It looks like it does not like ngSanitize gives me 'Error: [$injector:modulerr]'

Comment: you need to add angular sanitize in your scripts, http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular-sanitize.js

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you can use the `ng-bind-html-unsafe` directory to make it parse the text into html.

```
<pre ng-bind-html-unsafe="output"></pre>
```

Comment: The `ng-bind-html-unsafe` directive was removed from the AngularJS framework ages ago.

Comment: @georgeawg I have no clue myself.  It simply worked in the fiddle they provided.  So if that fiddle contains the version of angular they are using, I would expect it to work.

Comment: That fiddle uses AngularJS v1.1.1. It's obsolete and lacks the latest security patches.

Comment: @georgeawg So tell that to the author.

Comment: @Taplar It is working on jsfiddle which is running 1.1.1 but not in my app which is running 1.3.0-beta.5. jsfiddle does not have the option for this particular version to test.